# Doubt about the logic defining transitivity of a relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, definition, relations, solution-verification

Kindly, correct me where I am wrong.
*Modified(11:50 AM, 26 March 20): [ for all a, b, c ∈ X ]*
Let us define P: $(a, b), (b, c)∈R$ ; and Q: $(a, c)∈R$;
[A] When **P is true**:

1. P is true, Q is true: Relation is **TRANSITIVE**.
2. P is true, Q is false: Relation is **NOT TRANSITIVE**.

[B] When **P is false**
Now, I am going to deal with the condition **P is false** in this way.
Consider the first case, (P is true and Q is true) $\implies$ Relation is TRANSITIVE.
Then, the negation of this will be (P is false or Q is false) $\implies$ Relation is NOT TRANSITIVE.
This implies that the condition **P is false** is enough to say that the relation is **NOT TRANSITIVE**.
Is my argument valid?

Comment: What do you mean by defining P as “if $(a,b),(b,c) \in R$”? This is not even a complete sentence.

Comment: @fantasie : Kindly suggest the **IF-THEN** statement for definition of transitivity, then I will modify my question accordingly.

Comment: I think the logic of it would be a lot simpler if you use quantifiers. The issues you're having seem to stem from the fact that you're trying to define transitive without quantifiers.

Comment: @DanielApsley: I do not know the term *quantifier*. Kindly tell me, if this is the quantifier in this context: [ **for all a, b, c ∈ X**]?

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra That is correct. Quantifiers are essentially "for all" and "there exists". It is important to note that the negation of a quantifier is the other one. That is if for all x, P(x) is true, then the negation would be there exists y so that P(y) is not true.

Answer (score 2):

No, your argument is wrong because in your analysis of the notion of transitivity you omitted quantifiers and you destroyed the conditional (if... then) structure of the definition.

A binary relation $R$ (over a set $A$) is *transitive* when, for *every* $a, b, c \in A$, one has that $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ *imply* $(a,c) \in R$.

What is the negation of the condition above? We have to negate the universal quantifier and the implication!
So, the relation $R$ is *not transitive* when there *exist* $a,b,c \in A$ such that $(a,b) \in R, \, (b,c) \in R$ and $(a,c) \notin R$.

Therefore, to prove that $R$ is transitive you have to take *all* possible $a,b,c\in A$ (not necessarily distinct) and check that *if* $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ *then* $(a,c) \in R$. 
Note that in the particular case where  $(a,b) \notin R$ or $(b,c) \notin R$ the implication "if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ then $(a,c) \in R$" is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).
But you have to check that the implication "if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ then $(a,c) \in R$" holds for *all* $a, b, c \in A$ to conclude that $R$ is transitive.

---

Some errors in your analysis are the following:

1. Since you omitted quantifiers, you say that, given some $a, b, c \in A$, if you have that $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ and $(a,c) \in R$ then $R$ is transitive (case 1 in your analysis). 
   This is wrong, because you have shown this just for some $a,b,c \in A$, not for all $a, b, c \in A$.
2. Concerning your analysis in the case B, you misunderstand the meaning of the implication. 
   In propositional logic, if you are in a situation where $P$ and $Q$ are both true, then the implication $P \to Q$ is true but it does not mean that in all the other situations the implication $P \to Q$ is false. For instance, $P \to Q$ is true also when $P$ and $Q$ are both false.

Comment: Sorry, I was not familiar with the term *quantifiers*. I have modified the question and added  [**for all $a, b, c ∈ X$**]. Is this the quantifier you are mentioning?

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra - Yes, the _universal quantifier_ is an expression of the form "for every $a, b, c \in A$"; its dual is the _existential quantifier_, that is an expression of the form "there exist $a, b, c \in A$".

Comment: **“P and Q are both true, then the implication P→Q is true but it does not mean that in all the other situations the implication P→Q is false.”**
: This is what I am interested in. 
(1)  P and Q are both true, then the implication P→Q is true
: It does not mean that in all the other situations the implication P→Q is false. (as you said)
(2) P and Q are  ---, then the **implication P→Q is FALSE**
: Does it mean that in all the other situations the implication P→Q is TRUE? This is my question.

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra - Sorry, I am not sure to understand your question. In particular, I don't understand your point (2): what does "---" mean?

Comment: I may not be able to convey my message efficiently because English is not my native language. Let me try. Can we say that the negation of a positive statement does not mean all other situations are false, but negation of a negative statement means all other situations are TRUE?

Comment: [1] P→Q is true
: The negation of it = All other situations are false. (Wrong, as you said)
[2] P→Q is false
: The negation of it = All other situations are TRUE. (**Is it so?**)

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra - Not exactly. I'm saying the following: suppose that a proposition $A$ is true when at least one of the conditions $A_1, A_2, A_3$ is true. Then, the fact that $A_1$ doesn't hold, doesn't mean that $A$ is false, because possibly $A_2$ or $A_3$ is true.

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra - Concretely, the proposition $P \to Q$ is true when either (1) $P$ is true and $Q$ is true, or (2) $P$ is false and $Q$ is true, or (3) $P$ is false and $Q$ is false. The fact that you are _not_ in condition (1) doesn't mean that $P \to Q$ is false, because you might be in condition (2) or (3). 
In your argument, you say that since (1) doesn't hold, $P \to Q$ is false; but this is a wrong inference, as I explained above.

Comment: So, if we consider the truth table for this, there are 3 conditions for $P→Q$ to be true and only one condition for $P→Q$ to be false. That’s why, if we negate the TRUE in this case, we cannot say definitely that it will be false. But, if we negate FALSE in this case, we can definitely say that it will be true. Am I correct?

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra - Yes, more or less. More precisely, if you negate one of the three conditions where $P\to Q$ is true, then you can't say that $P \to Q$ is false, because possibly one of the other conditions where $P \to Q$ is true holds. But if you negate the _only_ condition where $P \to Q$ is false, then you can definitely say that $P \to Q$ is true.

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra - Now that the meaning of implication in propositional logic is clear (I hope!), think of the part of my answer about quantifiers. In my opinion, it is the most relevant to understand the definition of transitivity.